# Data loss with dask.dataframe.set_index(…, shuffle='disk')

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Thanks for a great and very useful package and for your amazing work. I'm not sure if this is the proper place for this issue. Apologies for that. There is a copy of this post at [github](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2226#issuecomment-673480714).

I get a result which to me is unexpected. I get substantial data loss (around half data gone) when using set_index(…, shuffle='disk') on a dask dataframe which have more than a few partitions (perhaps more than the number of nodes). When I redo the indexation a second time the issue gets even worse.

Same procedure works fine without data loss when I only use one node but still the distributed scheduler.

The [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html) states that:

> Some operations like set_index and merge/join are harder to do in a parallel or distributed setting than if they are in-memory on a single machine.

Is there an optimal way to sort data larger than memory using dask.distributed or is it better to use the default scheduler on a single machine?

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import dask.dataframe as dd
   ...: from dask_jobqueue import SLURMCluster
   ...: from dask.distributed import Client
   ...: cluster = SLURMCluster(
   ...:     cores=32,
   ...:     processes=32,
   ...:     memory="90GB"
   ...: )
   ...: cluster.scale(64)
   ...: client = Client(cluster)

In [2]: client.get_versions()['scheduler']
Out[2]:
{'host': {'python': '3.7.7.final.0',
  'python-bits': 64,
  'OS': 'Linux',
  'OS-release': '3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.nsc1.x86_64',
  'machine': 'x86_64',
  'processor': 'x86_64',
  'byteorder': 'little',
  'LC_ALL': 'None',
  'LANG': 'sv_SE'},
 'packages': {'python': '3.7.7.final.0',
  'dask': '2.22.0',
  'distributed': '2.22.0',
  'msgpack': '1.0.0',
  'cloudpickle': '1.5.0',
  'tornado': '6.0.4',
  'toolz': '0.10.0',
  'numpy': '1.19.1',
  'lz4': None,
  'blosc': None}}

In [2]: for n in [1e2, 1e3, 1e4, 1e5, 1.5e5, 2e5, 1e6]:
   ...:     n = int(n)
   ...:     pdf = dd.from_array(np.random.permutation(n).reshape(n, 1))
   ...:     n_tasks = len(pdf.set_index(0, shuffle='tasks'))
   ...:     n_disk  = len(pdf.set_index(0, shuffle='disk'))
   ...:     print(n_tasks, n_disk, pdf.npartitions)
   ...:
100 100 1
1000 1000 1
10000 10000 1
100000 100000 2
150000 150000 3
200000 127770 4
1000000 499914 20

In [3]: for n in [1e2, 1e3, 1e4, 1e5, 1.5e5, 2e5, 1e6]:
   ...:     n = int(n)
   ...:     pdf = dd.from_array(np.random.permutation(n).reshape(n, 1))
   ...:     n_tasks = len(pdf.set_index(0, shuffle='tasks'))
   ...:     n_disk  = len(pdf.set_index(0, shuffle='disk'))
   ...:     print(n_tasks, n_disk, pdf.npartitions)
   ...:
100 100 1
1000 1000 1
10000 10000 1
100000 100000 2
150000 83836 3
200000 120200 4
1000000 551936 20
```

Comment: Same issue with 2.23.0